# How does one diagnose a hardware vs software problem with a laptop keyboard backlight?

Tags: keyboard, hardware, backlight, diagnostic

I have Ubuntu 22.04 on a Dell Inspiron-7779 laptop. My keyboard backlight began to work intermittently and then failed completely. I'm trying to work out if this is a software issue or a hardware issue.

I could not find a backlight option in BIOS, but I am able to control the theoretical light level using the keyboard (F10) and CLI (brightnessctl) in Ubuntu:

```
Device 'dell::kbd_backlight' of class 'leds':
    Current brightness: 2 (100%)
    Max brightness: 2
```

If there's a loose connection internally, how could one diagnose this?

Comment: With apologies on behalf of the community, it looks like your question was spammed by a trio of bots that are posting multiple AI-generated answers on questions. Unfortunately, the majority of the Moderators on Stack Exchange sites (including Ask Ubuntu) are on strike *primarily* because the parent company has reduced their ability to remove these bogus answers.  We're hoping that things get back to normal shortly, but in the meantime, we're having to deal with stuff like this.

Comment: At some point, the AI-generated answers below will be removed, so it's possible they'll already be gone by the time you check back in here. In that case, you'll just be thoroughly confused on what I'm talking about ;-).